# ReactPHP HTTP Server Running Async

Tags: php, httpserver, reactphp

I was wondering if there is a way to have a ReactPHP HTTP Server handle requests Asynchronously. I set up a very basic HTTP Server using the documentation (https://github.com/reactphp/http)

`HTTPServer.php`

```
<?php

$httpServer = new React\Http\Server(
    function(Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request) {
        $responseData = $request->getUri()->getPath();
        if($responseData == "/testSlow") {sleep(5);} // simulate a slow response time
        if($responseData == "/testFast") {sleep(1);} // simulate a fast response time
        return new React\Http\Message\Response(
            "200",
            array("Access-Control-Allow-Headers" => "*", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*", "Content-Type" => "application/json"),
            json_encode($responseData)
        );
    }
);

$socketServer = new React\Socket\Server("0.0.0.0:31");
$httpServer->listen($socketServer);

?>
```

It seems to working fine but Synchronously, if I send a request to the `/testSlow` path and then immediately to the `/testFast` path, the slow one will always finish first after 5 seconds and only once it has finished will the fast one then start and finish after 1 second

Am I missing some additional setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReactPHP's **event loop** handles requests **asynchronously**, not **in parallel**. It means that there is only one running process. And call to **sleep()** hangs this process, i.e. prevents event loop from handling next requests. So, in asynchronous apps (in Node.js as well) it is a common practice to move heavy processing to dedicated processes.

I am not ReactPHP expert, so cannot provide a working example, but can point the root cause of the problem. I would recommend to read this awesome blog: https://sergeyzhuk.me/reactphp-series, and this article in particular: https://sergeyzhuk.me/2018/05/04/reactphp-child-processes

Answer (score 0):

ReactPHP uses an EventLoop and works on single threaded PHP. This means that by calling `sleep()` in your code you block the main thread, therefore the EventLoop is blocked and ReactPHP and the PHP process won't do anything for the time sleeping. Instead of using `sleep()` you need to set a timer on the event loop.

Here is your example script rewritten:

```php
<?php
$httpServer = new React\Http\Server(
    function(Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request) {
        $responseData = $request->getUri()->getPath();

        $timeout = 0;
        if($responseData == "/testSlow") { // simulate a slow response time
            $timeout = 5;
        }
        if($responseData == "/testFast") { // simulate a fast response time
            $timeout = 1;
        }

        // create a promise that will resolve after $timeout seconds
        $promise = new React\Promise\Promise(function ($resolve, $reject) use ($timeout) {
            React\EventLoop\Loop::addTimer($timeout, function () use ($resolve) {
                $resolve();
            });
        });

        // when the promise is resolved, this callback will create the HTTP response
        return $promise->then(function () use ($responseData) {
            return new React\Http\Message\Response(
                "200",
                array("Access-Control-Allow-Headers" => "*", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*", "Content-Type" => "application/json"),
                json_encode($responseData)
            );
        });
    }
);

$socketServer = new React\Socket\Server("0.0.0.0:8080");
$httpServer->listen($socketServer);

?>
```

You can find more docs and examples on this topic in the official documentation of the `react/http` library and this specific bit at: https://github.com/reactphp/http#deferred-response.

Hope this helps!